# Using canvas, how to cut holes with inset shadows into an image?

Tags: javascript, canvas, shadow

Using `canvas`, I'm trying to cut a series of round holes into an image. Additionally, each hole should have an inset drop shadow that would make it look as if the image is slightly hovering over the background.

Here is what I've managed to do:

1. Cut holes into an image using `globalCompositeOperation = "destination-top"`
2. Cut out *one* hole from a background *shape* using "opposite winding" (drawing counter-clockwise, then clockwise)

The second attempt, however, does not seem to be viable for *multiple* holes on an *image* for these two reasons:

- AFAIK, can't draw an image counter-clockwise
- AFAIK, for [opposite drawing technique](https://bocoup.com/blog/can-i-draw-an-inset-shadow-with-the-html5-canvas-api) to work, I can't close the path in between calls to `arc`

Here is what I currently have:

```js
let cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
let img = new Image();
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 256, 256);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  hole(ctx, 64, 64, 32);
  hole(ctx, 192, 64, 32);
  hole(ctx, 64, 192, 32);
  hole(ctx, 192, 192, 32);
});
img.src = "https://placeimg.com/256/256/nature";

function hole(ctx, x, y, r, ccw=false) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, ccw);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

How can I now add inset shadows to the holes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a second canvas to help create the effect you're after, alongside shadowOffset and shadowColor.

```js
let cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
let img = new Image();

img.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let cvs2 = document.createElement('canvas');
  cvs2.width = 256;
  cvs2.height = 256;
  ctx2 = cvs2.getContext("2d");

  hole(ctx2, 64, 64, 32);
  hole(ctx2, 192, 64, 32);
  hole(ctx2, 64, 192, 32);
  hole(ctx2, 192, 192, 32);

  ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = "source-out";
  ctx2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 256, 256);

  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 4;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 8;
  ctx.shadowColor = 'black';
  ctx.drawImage(cvs2, 0, 0, 256, 256);
});
img.src = "https://placeimg.com/256/256/nature";

function hole(ctx, x, y, r, ccw = false) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, ccw);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put a div behind each hole and play around with the inset shadows in those to get a suitable effect (though the simple shadow in this snippet makes it look more like a button sticking out rather than a hole in I realize)

```js
let cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
let img = new Image();
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 256, 256);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  hole(ctx, 64, 64, 32);
  hole(ctx, 192, 64, 32);
  hole(ctx, 64, 192, 32);
  hole(ctx, 192, 192, 32);
});
img.src = "https://placeimg.com/256/256/nature";

function hole(ctx, x, y, r, ccw=false) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, ccw);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 10px gray inset;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: transparent;
  clear: both;
}
div.shadow:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 29px;
  left: 29px;
}
div.shadow:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 157px;
  left: 29px;
}
div.shadow:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 29px;
  left: 157px;
}
div.shadow:nth-of-type(4) {
  top: 157px;
  left: 157px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow"></div>
<div class="shadow"></div>
<div class="shadow"></div>
<div class="shadow"></div>
<canvas width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can not make use of additional markup, as I have to work within the `canvas` so that I can later export everything as an image. However, it is a creative idea that will hopefully be of use to other people coming here in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn’t realise that. So you’ll need to draw on the canvas itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with a single canvas by drawing your canvas over itself, with a huge offset for the shadow.
Having this huge offset allows us to actually draw the canvas outside of its visible rectangle, but to still keep the shadows.

```js
let cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
let img = new Image();
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 256, 256);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  hole(ctx, 64, 64, 32);
  hole(ctx, 192, 64, 32);
  hole(ctx, 64, 192, 32);
  hole(ctx, 192, 192, 32);
  ctx.fill(); // single filling is always preferable
  
  // offset by the size of the canvas + the actual offset wanted
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = cvs.width + 4;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = cvs.height + 4;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 4;
  ctx.shadowColor = "black";
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
  // draw at the inverse offset (so the shadow is at the correct position)
  ctx.drawImage( cvs, -cvs.width, -cvs.height );
});
img.src = "https://placeimg.com/256/256/nature";

function hole(ctx, x, y, r, ccw=false) {
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, ccw);
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

```html
<canvas width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found one possible approach myself, but I think it is more complicated than it needs to be:

1. draw the holes with `globalCompositeOperation` set to `destination-out` as I was already doing; this will cut them out of the image, creating literal holes that reveal the background
2. set appropriate `shadow*` and `lineWidth` values; the latter will affect the shadow intensity, where a thicker line makes for a more intense shadow
3. using `stroke()`, draw one additional circle per hole with `globalCompositeOperation` set to `destination-over`, which will draw *behind* existing content; to prevent the actual stroke from being visible, add its `lineWidth` to the radius used for the holes

```js
let cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
let img = new Image();
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 256, 256);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    hole(ctx, 64, 64, 32);
    hole(ctx, 192, 64, 32);
    hole(ctx, 64, 192, 32);
    hole(ctx, 192, 192, 32);
});
img.src = "https://placeimg.com/256/256/nature";

function hole(ctx, x, y, r) {
    let lw = r * 0.2;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
    ctx.lineWidth = lw;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.shadowColor = "black";
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = r * 0.1;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = r * 0.1;
    ctx.shadowBlur = r * 0.2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r + lw, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

```html
<canvas width="256" height="256"></canvas>
```